# Calling PL/SQL procedure with SYS_REFCURSOR as IN parameter using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters, plsql, cursor

**I am trying to understand how I can call a PL/SQL procedure which takes a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `IN` parameter.**

Consider the following PL/SQL procedure:

```
print_cursor_contents(myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR , row_count OUT NUMBER);
```

At the time of binding value to the IN parameter which `setXXX` method do I use ?

To me a java Class with individual cursor record fields , as it members and a Array of instances of this class seems the proper way to represent a plsql CURSOR. I get a SQLException when I do this:

I used the following set method

```
         callStmt.setObject(1, curRec);
```

Here is the exception I got for using the above statement:

```
Exception occured in the database
Exception message: Invalid column type
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8921)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9176)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:5024)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:234)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.printMaxSalAllDept(HrManager.java:1022)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.main(HrManager.java:1116)
Database error code: 17004
```

Comment: Here is a solution to pass SYS_REFCURSOR from Java directly without saving data to database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865207/create-and-pass-sys-refcursor-as-an-input-parameter-to-oracle-procedure-from-jav/45881113#45881113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me a java Class with individual cursor record fields , as it members and a Array of instances of this class seems the proper way to represent a plsql CURSOR.

I disagree.

If you have a stored function or procedure that either returns a ref cursor or has a ref cursor as an `OUT` parameter, the ref cursor comes out of JDBC as a `ResultSet`.  So, if it were possible to call a stored procedure with a `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameter, I'd suspect that a `ResultSet` would be what you would need to pass.

In fact, my suspicions are confirmed.  If you take a look at Oracle's extension to `CallableStatement`, [`OracleCallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html), it inherits a [`setCursor(int, ResultSet)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setCursor_int__java_sql_ResultSet_) method from its superinterface `OraclePreparedStatement`.  Therefore, you could cast the `CallableStatement` to `OracleCallableStatement`, call the `setCursor` method, and away you go.

Except this approach doesn't actually work.

If you try calling `setCursor` on an `OracleCallableStatement`, you will get an exception `java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature`.

You can try calling`setObject` with a `ResultSet`, but you will only get another `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type` exception.

Here's a test class you can run to verify either case.  It calls one stored procedure to get a ref cursor (and hence a `ResultSet`) and then tries to pass it to the other:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;

public class JavaRefCursorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "user", "password");

        try (CallableStatement cstmt1 = conn.prepareCall(
                "{ call java_ref_curs_test.get_ref_cursor(?)}")) {
            cstmt1.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cstmt1.execute();

            try (ResultSet rSet = (ResultSet)cstmt1.getObject(1)) {
                try (CallableStatement cstmt2 = conn.prepareCall(
                        "{ call java_ref_curs_test.print_refcursor(?)}")) {

                    // Uncomment the next line to call setCursor:
                    // ((OracleCallableStatement)cstmt2).setCursor(1, rSet); 

                    // Uncomment the next line to call setObject:
                    // cstmt2.setObject(1, rSet);

                    cstmt2.execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(The two procedures in the `java_ref_curs_test` take a single `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameter: `get_ref_cursor` returns a ref cursor and `print_refcursor` takes one as a parameter but does nothing with it.)

So, which `setXXX` method should you use?  I would say none of them.  What you are asking for is not possible directly.

It may still be possible to call this procedure, but you will have to create the ref cursor in PL/SQL, not in Java, and then pass it to your procedure.

For example, I could use the following PL/SQL block to call the two procedures used in the above example:

```
DECLARE
   l_curs   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   java_ref_curs_test.get_ref_cursor(l_curs);
   java_ref_curs_test.print_refcursor(l_curs); 
END;
```

You can fairly easily run this from JDBC: put it in a string and pass it to `Statement.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: I tried creating a "ResultSet" by executing a select query and then  passing that to the procedure using setCursor. I am getting the Unsupported feature sql exception too . Even though I am using the latest oracle Jdbc jar